# How to simulate/preview fixed viewport width on desktop browser developer tools?

Tags: viewport, firefox-developer-tools, safari-web-inspector

My site have a fixed viewport width set like so:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1260px, maximum-scale=1">
```

This makes the site "shrink" to fit the width of the device, and works well on any browser I use on iOS or Android.

I want to know if there's any way to preview this on developer tools responsive mode in a Firefox or Safari desktop browser. I'm only able to preview this on Chrome.

In Chrome it shrinks according to the width. In Firefox/Safari it keeps 1:1 pixel ratio.

Comment: Please provide example code and screenshots of what it is you are wanting to see.

Answer (score 0):

The Responsive Design Mode of the Firefox DevTools currently doesn't take the information of the `<viewport>` element into account.

This feature is requested in [bug 774055](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774055).